# where is gray square for the footer row of the outermost group in SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have SQL Server 2008R2 and SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio that came with it.

I am reading Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services by Brian Larson. On page 318 he says "Click the gray square for the footer row of the outermost group. Modify the
following properties for this footer row using the Properties window:"

Where is this gray square?

Thank you

**EDITED**

I have managed to find it. It was the cells below Hours Worked. The webpage says I have to wait for 7-8 hours to answer my own question.

Comment: if you found it, you should probably answer your own question and not just put a note into where you found it.  Just a thought.

Comment: I wasn't allowed because a message said I don't have enough points to closed it straight away. I had to wait for another 7-9 hours. Honest I am telling the truth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find it. It was the cells below Hours Worked. I will try to close this if I am allowed otherwise I wil